# Getting 'MissingPropertyException: No such property' error for a Domain class that has composite key

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am using Groovy/Grails Tool Suite Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE with Grails2.4.4 and JRE1.8 .
In a very simple scaffold project, I have a domain class called Book and trying to create a composite key. But after I run the project and as I click on 'Create New Book' link, I get error :
**"Caused by MissingPropertyException: No such property: generator for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.CompositeIdentity"**

My Book class looks as below:

```
class Book implements Serializable{
    String title;
    String author;

    static constraints = {
        title (blank: false)
        author (blank: false)
    }
    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['title','author']
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @shas, Didi you find solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, it is looking for `generator`. Try this:

```
id composite: ['title','author'], generator: 'assigned'
```

Comment: It could be related to this ticket [https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10018](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10018). I am working on grails 2.4.5 and have used, numerous times, composite id with `generator: 'assigned'`.